# Comparison of Analysis within SonarQube 6.1

Tags: sonarqube

A few days ago I've upgraded from SonarQube 5.3 to SonarQube 6.1.

Now I'm missing the Dropdown to set the Leak Period I'm interested in.
The configuration values are still there (Administration - General - Differential View - Leak Period / Period 2 / Period 3) but within every view there is only "... since last analysis" available.

Is it not possible anymore to dynamically change the periods I'm interested in? Is there another way to compare Analysis? (e.g. last 30 days, last week etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with version 5.6, SonarQube helps you focus on the Leak Period, to keep new code clean. The other side of that coin is that access to the other differential periods has been dropped. You can consider the administrative settings vestigial: useless remnants left behind by evolution. They will be removed "soon".